# ARM NetBSD5.1 Pthread support

Tags: arm, pthreads, netbsd

I have NetBSD5.1 source. I have compiled the kernel and userland with the source. When I native compile a sample C program with pthread_create() in ARM NetBSD5.1, it is crashing. Same program is running successfuly in my Linux PC. Want to know if Pthread is supported in ARM machine which run NetBSD5.1 OS?

Note: other sample C programs native compiled in ARM machine runs successfully.

Comment: @greg-a-woods  I have somehow able to arrive at this bt  (gdb) bt
#0  0x4003ad5c in pthread_setcancelstate () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x400af724 in inet_network () from /usr/lib/libc.so.12
#2  0x400af724 in inet_network () from /usr/lib/libc.so.12
Previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
  also I compiled the program statically and I got this  #0  0x000232b4 in __flockfile_internal ()
#1  0x00022ae0 in fflush ()
#2  0x00022ae0 in fflush ()
  Any clue to debug this?  Moving to the latest NetBSD is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I think.  (I don't have an ARM system running 5.1 at the moment -- mine are running a pre-7.0 -current.)

If you can show some more details about the crash, e.g. stack backtraces from the debugger, then perhaps I or someone else can provide more help.

Comment: @greg-a-woods Thasnks a lot. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x64aa0640 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x64aa0640 in ?? ()
#1  0x4003ae64 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x4003ae64 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)  <br/> Its just a simple program with pthread_create(). the same program is executing successfully in i386.

Comment: Perhaps if you can compile with `-g` to get debug symbols then the backtrace would be more meaningful.  Perhaps you could also edit your question and insert a copy of the full source for your test program.  I'm still not sure if pthreads should work on NetBSD/arm-5.1 but I have no problem running test programs with pthreads on NetBSD/arm-7.99.8 on my RPi B+.  Perhaps you could upgrade to NetBSD-7.

Comment: I have compiled my program with -g and the libraries are saying "not stripped" as well. Maybe there is some bug with gdb.